# Pandas: Replace a column within a data frame by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have a column wihtin my csv file which contains a tuple as value.
E.g. One value : 10.000 , 20.000

My aim is to split and replace the column by the two new columns.

I already tried the following:

```
brokerMktPrices["nameOfColumn"] = pd.DataFrame(brokerMktPrices["nameOfColumn"].str.split(' ',1).tolist(), columns = ['firstNewColumn','secondNewColumn'])
```

But this leads to a column which contains only the first value of the tuple (the left value). So the `secondNewColumn` is missing !

I also tried some cumbersome stuff like adding the two new columns at the end of my data frame and then deleting the `nameOfColumn`column ! But I think there have to be a better solution for my problem !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need if values are tuples:

```
brokerMktPrices = pd.DataFrame({'nameOfColumn':[(10.000 , 20.000),(10.000 , 20.000)]})
print (brokerMktPrices)
   nameOfColumn
0  (10.0, 20.0)
1  (10.0, 20.0)

df = pd.DataFrame(brokerMktPrices["nameOfColumn"].values.tolist())
print (df)
      0     1
0  10.0  20.0
1  10.0  20.0
```

If values are strings:

```
brokerMktPrices = pd.DataFrame({'nameOfColumn':['10.000 , 20.00','10.000 , 20.000']})

df = brokerMktPrices["nameOfColumn"].str.split('\s+,\s+', expand=True)
print (df)
        0       1
0  10.000   20.00
1  10.000  20.000
```

and last assign to new columns:

```
brokerMktPrices[["c", "b"]] = df
print (brokerMktPrices)
      nameOfColumn       c       b
0   10.000 , 20.00  10.000   20.00
1  10.000 , 20.000  10.000  20.000
```

Comment: The second approach works well :) Thanks for that ! And how can I add the new columns after the "nameOfColumn" column? The example was just a little snippet ! In my case after the "NameOfColumn" multiple other column take place

Comment: I think there is possible reindex columns or use `insert` like `brokerMktPrices.insert(1, 'b', df[0])
brokerMktPrices.insert(2, 'c', df[1])`